# Mouse Listener outside a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I have perused other's questions and i don't think the subject i'm about to ask for is mentioned... Here is my problem:

I have an idea for a project in Java that has a mouse listener but for actions outside a panel or any gui. The basic idea is that the application when it's running listens for double clicks and then trigger the webcam, takes a photo and then send it to an e-mail... I think that triggering the webcam, taking the photo and sending to an e-mail is doable, but i have no idea if the mouse listener I'm looking for is plausible.

So, to sum it up: Is it possible to have a mouse listener that listens to actions that are not happening on a application per se? If so, what is the function i'm looking for?

Comment: In Java, no, not without JNI or JNA support and, as a user, no, please don't screw with my double clicks, I'd be posting content all over the place ... mostly when I don't want to...

Comment: Java is not the tool for this as you will want a language that allows you to get close to the OS, something Java has been studiously built **not** to do so it can be as OS agnostic as possible.

Comment: This would be a serious security bug in any OS that let you do this kind o thing. I am unaware of any modern OS that would permit this